# How to subtract the values within array in perl?

Tags: perl

How to subtract the succeeding value by the preceding value?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @hus = qw(7 9 12 16 20 21);
my ($i,$j);
for($i = 0; $i <= $#hus; $i++){
   for($j = 1; $j <= $#hus; $j++){
        my $m = $hus[$j]-$hus[$i];
        print "$m\n";
    }
}
```

In this program gives the output. But i expect particular output such as 2 3 4 4 1. This output is comes from 9-7=2, 12-9=3, 16-12=4, 20-16=4, 21-20=1. How to print the particular outputs?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this quite compactly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @hus = qw(7 9 12 16 20 21);
print $hus[$_] - $hus[$_-1], "\n" for 1 .. $#hus;
```

The expression `1 .. $#hus` generates a list of numbers from 1 to the index of the last element of the array `@hus`. The `for` loop goes through this list, assigning the current value to the special variable `$_`. This means that the two elements you're interested in are at position `$_` and `$_-1` of `@hus`.

Output:

```
2
3
4
4
1
```

Comment: This is Perl, not Ruby, so there are no splats. `1 .. $#hus` is a *list* generated by the *range operator*

Comment: Thanks. I also can't see how it's anything like a Ruby splat!

Comment: @Borodin you're right, a splat is a completely different thing. I was thinking of something else, although I can't remember what. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to loop through the array once.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @hus = qw( 7 9 12 16 20 21 );

for (my $i = 0; $i < $#hus; ++$i) {
    my $m = $hus[$i+1] - $hus[$i];
    print "$m\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
4
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating *forward differences*. It can be done very simply like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @hus = qw( 7 9 12 16 20 21 );
my @diff = map { $hus[$_] - $hus[$_-1] } 1 .. $#hus;
print "@diff\n";
```

**output**

```
2 3 4 4 1
```

---

**Update**

Perhaps you want the output that you show in your question? You can do that like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @hus = qw(7 9 12 16 20 21);

print join ', ', map {
  my ($i, $j) = @hus[$_-1, $_];
  sprintf('%d-%d=%d', $j, $i, $j-$i);
} 1 .. $#hus;
print "\n";
```

**output**

```
9-7=2, 12-9=3, 16-12=4, 20-16=4, 21-20=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 5 iterations for 6 elements, or more generically, you need to loop one fewer times than the number of elements in `@hus`. This whole nested loop approach is wrong because `$i` should always be one less than `$j`. Fixed:

```
my ($i,$j);
for ($j = 1; $j <= $#hus; $j++) {
   my $i = $j-1;
   my $m = $hus[$j]-$hus[$i];
   print "$m\n";
}
```

But let's clean that up.

```
for my $i (1..$#hus) {
   print $hus[$i]-$hus[$i-1], "\n";
}
```

You could even reduce it to the following:

```
say $hus[$_]-$hus[$_-1] for 1..$#hus;
```